# Dismissing modalviewcontroller issue

Tags: iphone

What is the a way for the modal controller to talk to the presenting controller.

In my case i m presenting modalviewcontroller without using delegate. But want to dismiss modalviewcontroller using delegate protocol.

SO can i dismiss modalviewcontroller using delegate protocol where i m presenting modalviewcontroller without using delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal controller can dismiss itself. Within the modal view controller, use `[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES]` (or NO if you don't want to animate it). If you include that line of code in the modal controller, then you should be okay!

> dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
>
> The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal view controller it presented using the presentModalViewController:animated: method. If you call this method on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view controller.

via [iOS Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can also access the parent view controller through `[self.parentViewController ...]`